# TypeError at /api/v1/accounts/me/ getMe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a Django project  using django-rest-framewok versioning.
I am facing with a weird problem saying unexpected keyword argument named version.

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ScreenShotUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


def getMe(self,request):
      user = ScreenShotUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
      return Response(user)
```

project url.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r 'users', views.UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
  url(r '^api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/accounts/', include('Accounts.urls')),
]
```

and The accounts application's urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^me/$', views.getMe),
 ]
```

when I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/accounts/me/
I got error like this

```
TypeError at /api/v1/accounts/me/
getMe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/accounts/me/
Django Version: 1.9.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
getMe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 147
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/Working_repo/screenshot/ScreenShot',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_contrib_requestprovider-1.0.1-py3.5.egg',
 '/Working_repo/screenshot/ScreenShot',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Mar 2016 13:12:54 +0000
```

Django expert's please give me the hint I am missing. TIA

**EDIT**
I have got solution concept form **Shang Wang's** answer and this will be my solution

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getMe(request, version):
    user = ScreenShotUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    result = UserSerializer(user).data
    return Response(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have `(?P<version>(v1|v2))` defined in url, it means your views.py method is expecting to take a parameter `version`. But your `getMe` method doesn't have that as parameter, hence the error. Easy fix would be removing the named parameter in your url definition.

**Edit:**

You should take a look at [django doc about named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#named-groups), in python `(?P<name>pattern)` means a regex named group. If you have that in django url definition, it means you are passing a parameter to views.py method. I don't think your views.py method is using `version` parameter, so you shouldn't have that defined in url. You just do:

```
url(r '^api/v1|v2/accounts/', include('Accounts.urls')),
```

If you can't remove the `version` parameter because some other methods do need it, just define it in `getMe` method and don't use it for anything:

```
def getMe(self, request, version):
    user = ScreenShotUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    return Response(user)
```

Read more details in django doc on [how url dispatcher is working](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did't get your solution removing parameter in my url clearly. can you please explain it

Comment: If your solution is removing version parameters from url  then it is not possible because a lots of api is using version parameter right now except getMe method. So what should I do for getMe method

Comment: Shang Wang@ I am giving you an up vote and thanks for your reply. I have got solution concept from your answer but this did not solve my problem. I edited my question with solve